# Promise is returning object promise for a millisecond before actual promise response

Tags: typescript, promise

I am trying to do a basic check to see if an myAnswer has an answer or not  I have all that checking functionality working perfectly fine. My issue is that in the final function that is supposed to return the String I get from myAnswer it is returning [object Promise]. I have no idea why this is not returning my String directly instead of flashing [object promise] when I resolve the promise.

If I could get some assistance that would be great!

```
this.myAnswer = XapiStoreService.retrieveQuestionFillIn(this.app.getStudent(), pages[pageIndex])
                .then((answer:string) => {
                  this.myAnswer = answer;
                }, (reason:string) => {
                  this.myAnswer = '';
                });
```

Comment: That looks like TypeScript.

Comment: That's right @Herohtar

Comment: It's doing exactly what it is supposed to be doing. You can't return a value that doesn't exist yet, so instead it returns a promise.

Comment: @KevinB Yes that's right but I don't want to see the empty object until it resolves the promise

Comment: @GauravShinde Unfortunately, that's all you're gonna get. *that's just how it works.*

Comment: If you don't want `this.myAnswer` to be set until the promise resolves, don't assign `this.myAnswer` in the outer expression. Just let your `then` callback on the promise assign to `this.myAnswer`. In any case you can't get a value out immediately, you have to wait for the promise to resolve.

Comment: You're using TypeScript. So use types. If you did, you would see that myAnswer is initialized with a promise, and then initialized with a string. Decide what it should be: a promise, or a string? If it's a promise, you can use the async pipe to display it. If it's a string, then you shouldn't assign the promise to it. Only the value resolved by the promise.

Comment: Thank you @DanielPryden

Comment: Thank you @JBNizet

Answer (score 2):

You're doing

```
this.myAnswer = XapiStoreService.retrieveQuestionFillIn(…).then(…);
```

which assigns a promise to `myAnswer`. That's the one you shortly see before the promise settles and overwrites the `myAnwer`. You probably instead want something like

```
this.myAnswer = "loading";
XapiStoreService.retrieveQuestionFillIn(this.app.getStudent(), pages[pageIndex]).then((answer:string) => {
    this.myAnswer = answer;
}, (reason:string) => {
    this.myAnswer = 'error';
    console.error(reason);
});
```